# How to print first input a set number of times from second input which also multiplies based on odds or even

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to programming.I am trying to create a program where the first input is printed the number taken from second input.But I also have to make the print multiply based on the name it's odd or even.For Example,

```
Sample Input :
first input = "CSE110"
Second input 4
Desired output:
CSE110CSE110CSE110CSE110CSE110CSE110CSE110CSE110

Explanation: The second input which is the number 4 is even, therefore the first string input 'CSE110' is concatenated(joined together) 4*2 = 8 times.
```

```
inpStr = input("Enter String: ")
inpNum = int(input("Enter Number: "))

if inpNum > 0:
    for i in range(inpNum):
        print(inpStr,end="")
```

Comment: I cannot understand the output

Comment: *print multiply based on the name it's odd or even.For Example,* please elaborate

Comment: So if the second input is 4.it should print 8 times based of it's even.it should be as 4*2 =8.

Comment: so if the second input is an even number, you multiply it by 2?

Comment: yes and if its 3 and odd,it multiplies by 3

Comment: I have updated the question with explanation from the manual.But i don't know how to write it in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already got the code to print the first input `x` times. All you need to do is test if the second input is even or odd, and multiply by 2 or 3, respectively.

Test if an integer is odd or even using the [modulo operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations), `%`. `x % y` gives the remainder after the integer division of x by y.`x % 2` will be `0` for even `x` and `1` for odd `x`. E.g.

```
def iseven(x):
        return x % 2 == 0
```

You can use an `if` statement to update the value of `inpNum` accordingly. E.g.

```
if inpNum % 2 == 0:
        inpNum = inpNum * 2
else:
        inpNum = inpNum * 3
```

In fact, this might be a good use case for Python's [ternary operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), which leads to the one line:

```
inpNum = inpNum * 2 if inpNum % 2 == 0 else inpNum * 3
```

Now you can just use your existing code to print the output. The whole example would be:

```
inpStr = input("Enter String: ")
inpNum = int(input("Enter Number: "))

inpNum = inpNum * 2 if inpNum % 2 == 0 else inpNum * 3

if inpNum > 0:
    for i in range(inpNum):
        print(inpStr,end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inpStr = input("Enter String: ")
inpNum = int(input("Enter Number: "))

if len(inpStr)%2 == 0:
    print(inpStr*inpNum*2)
else:
    print(inpStr*inpNum*3)
```